# How to check if UDP port is open or closed

Tags: c#

I want to iterate UDP port from 5000 to 50xx

How can I check if a specific port is already open or free to use?

I use this code but it always returns false:

```
public bool PortIsUsed(int myport)
{
   bool alreadyinuse = (from p in System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveUdpListeners() where p.Port == myport select p).Count() == 1;
   return alreadyinuse;
}
```

Comment: What have you attempted? Post some code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Hint: Use the [UdpClient.Connect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.connect.aspx) method.

Comment: Are you checking it on this on the host machine or on the machine you're trying to connect to?

Comment: @ikh on the host machine

Answer (score 1):

Normally when asking for a shared resource such as UDP port numbers, asking "is this available right now?" is not productive. Whichever answer you get may become incorrect in the next microsecond, as another application could change something that invalidates the answer.

What you can do is ask the OS to listen on a specific port ("acquire" the resource). The OS will either say *yes*, and here's a handle or whatever, or *no*, some other process is using that particular port. Either way, you get an answer that you can definitively act on. (Specifically, if you get *no* for an answer, try a different port.)